# Get Unique ID for Receipient / Current Chat in Telegram Bot Inline Query?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am working on a Telegram Bot in Python that should work inline and the answer to an inline query with different results, depending on what chat you are in.

But at the moment, i can only get my own ID. I need to somehow get either a Chat-ID or a receipient User-ID, or Groupchat-ID for Groups.

I have already tried checking out the data that comes with the inline-query, but besides Identifiers for my own User, it doesn't seem to have any information to create a unique identifier for the current chat.

I also tried interacting with the bot from both sides to see if that would change anything, but same result from both sides, all the info in the query can only identify the sender but not the recipient or chat-ID

Is there a way to get this info from a inline request? ´
Or any ideas for a workaround?

For context, I want to create a To-Do-List on a per-Chat basis, so for example my brother and I see the same To-Do-List when we are in our Chat. Same with groups.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get this info from a inline request?

No. You have already answered that question here:

> I have already tried checking out the data that comes with the inline-query, but besides Identifiers for my own User, it doesn't seem to have any information to create a unique identifier for the current chat.

The [`InlineQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery) not containing information about the chat that the query is made in also makes sense, because the bot doesn't even need to be a member of that chat.